# How to compose a HTTP request with a custom HTTP method type

Tags: http, httprequest, http-method

Is there a tool which enables me to prepare a custom HTTP request. I need to request ressources which are bound to custom HTTP methods on server side. 
I know about the fire fox plugin `RESTClient` which is pretty perfect, except that I can't set a custom HTTP method type like: `FOO`.

**EDIT**

I found out that the `RESTClient` plugin also provides the possibility to create custom HTTP methods. It's the same as with `Fiddler`. But however, `Fiddler` is a nice alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest something similar to [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Postman supports custom HTTP methods...

[image: postman example]

Source: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/166